# When OnConnected is called in LocationCallbacks?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am developing an Android App with MapsActivity. I am implementing LocationListener and Callbacks to track change in user location. I am overriding OnConnected method in the interface, which creates LocationRequest object. When I debug the app, it is never executed. Can anyone inform me where and when the OnConnect is called. I am only creating GoogleApiClient in onCreate method, do I have to create external call to it?

Comment: Can you post your code related to your location stuff?

Answer (score 2):

When you creating GoogleApiClient, also you need to implement listener to listen when GoogleApiClient is connected.
Refer [This link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks#onConnected(android.os.Bundle))